# Multiple buttons to start different activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I have been trying to have my home menu working. I have 2 `Buttons` and I want them to start different activities when clicked.

this is my code

```
package com.example.clicktothink_1;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button btn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.play_btn);
    Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.howToPlay_btn);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,QuizActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HowActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);

        }
    });



}
}
```

I have already declared both activities in the manifest file. The first `Intent` works

`Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,QuizActivity.class);`

however the second `Intent` does not. Any idea how to get this working ?

stacktrace

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 19; columnNumber: 40; Open quote is expected for         attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "android:parentActivityName".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.common.xml.AndroidManifestParser.parse(AndroidManifestParser.java:612)
    at     com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper.parseUnchecked(AndroidManifestHelper.java:75)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.build(PreCompilerBuilder.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

here is the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        package="com.example.clicktothink_1"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
           android:minSdkVersion="16"
           android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >


            <activity
                android:name="com.example.clicktothink_1.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >

                <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>

                <intent-filter>
                     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />    
                </intent-filter>

            </activity>

            <activity android:name="com.example.clicktothink_1.HowActivity"/>          
            <activity android:name="com.example.clicktothink_1.QuizActivity"/>      
            <activity android:name="com.example.clicktothink_1.ResultActivity"/>

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: Define "not working". Crashing, doing nothing, etc...?

Comment: sorry, that would be crashing ..

Comment: Then post the stacktrace so we can help you figure out *why* and *where* it is crashing.

Comment: Post the error that you are getting.

Comment: whether you declared HowActivity.java in manifest file?

Comment: The problem is in the AndroidManifest, can you post your manifest?

Comment: This is not your complete manifest **or** stacktrace

Comment: @codeMagic sorry bout that, already edited the manifest file ..

Comment: perhaps there is extra space in `manifest` file properly format maifest pressing `ctrl+shift+f` together then clean ur project and run it

Comment: @kaushik thanks but problem is still there ..

Comment: @mae is your problem is solved?

Comment: @Ajay not yet .. tried changing the value of the (toActivity.class) it worked but when i change it back to HowActivity.class the problem comes back

Comment: @mae why don't you delete extra intent filters (lower),android:layout_width and android:layout_height from androidmanifest.xml and then check it

Comment: @Ajay thanks! deleting the android:layout_width and height solved my problem .. would you mind explaining your solution ?

Comment: @mae if(satisfied) accept my answer

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button btn;
    private Button btn1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       this.btn  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play_btn);
       this.btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.howToPlay_btn);

       btn.setOnClickListener(this);
       btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

   public void onClick(View v) {
       int id = v.getId();

       if (id == this.btn.getId()) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuizActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
       }

       else if (id == this.btn1.getId()){
           Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, HowActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent1);
       }
   }

}
```

If doesn't work, take a look in the logcat.

Comment: Mind explaining *what* you have changed and *why* it should work for the OP? As far as I can tell, you just changed to use one `onClick()` instead of two, which isn't the problem. And changed from an anonymous `OnClick` class to implementing the interface.

Answer (score -1):

```
 if(check manifest file(androidmanifest.xml)){

    if(check activity_main.xml(check all id are specified correctly)){


         public void onClick(View v) {

          switch(v.getId()){
             case R.id.play_btn :
             Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, QuizActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
             break;
             case R.id.howtoplay_btn:
             Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HowActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);

             break;
            }
       }
    }else{
      correct activity_main.xml
   }
}else{
 Delete android:layout_width and android:layout_height from the android:manifest.xml.      
 Your application will run.

    If you want to know the reason read
```

[http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html]
    }

Comment: Mind explaining what you have changed and why it should work for the OP? Becuase, obviously, this code isn't going to compile

Comment: @codemagic you are right this code is not going to compile ...this is a logical code ...applying some checking method given in code can help in correcting the problem